# 2 Rectangles, Overlap, intersect, union. JUnit Failed: testNotOverlaps(RectangleGraderTest)

Tags: java, junit, junit4

A little frustrated trying to figure this one out, trying to fix this bug, and coming to you guys after trying it out a lot myself. I am required to create a Java program that allows to run some functions on 2 rectangles (similar to maps). 2 of the rectangles I test using JUnit 4 (another requirement) comes out as 'true' for an overlap, but they should not overlap. The message is:

"Failed: testNotOverlaps(RectangleGraderTest)
Message: x:0, y:0, w:20, h:10 should not overlap with x:-50, y:-50, w:5, h:5 but it does."

The screenshot and my code and the title is pretty self-explanatory. I keep getting this bug, I need it to go away. I am happy to answer any further questions :)

Rectangle.java:

```js
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
/**
 * This class represents a rectangle. A has x and y coordinates and width and height.
 */

public class Rectangle {
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int width;
  private int height;

  /**
   * Constructs a rectangle object and initializes it with the given x, y, height and width.
   *
   * @param x      the x coordinate of this rectangle
   * @param y      the y coordinate of this rectangle
   * @param height the height of this rectangle
   * @param width  the width of this rectangle
   * @throws IllegalStateException if width or/and height is non-positive
   */
  public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    if (height <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Height can't be non-positive.");
    }
    if (width <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width can't be non-positive.");
    }
    if (width > 0) {
      this.width = width;
    }
    if (height > 0) {
      this.height = height;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if this rectangle overlaps with other, false otherwise.
   *
   * @param other the other rectangle
   * @return true if this rectangle overlaps with other, false otherwise.
   */
  public Boolean overlap(Rectangle other) {
    if (this.y > other.y + other.height && other.x < this.x + this.width
            || this.y + this.height > other.y && this.x < other.x + other.width
            || this.x > other.x && this.y > other.y && this.x + this.width < other.x + other.width
            && this.y + this.height < other.y + other.height) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns a Rectangle object that represents the overlap of the two rectangles, otherwise throws
   * a NoSuchElementException.
   *
   * @param other the other rectangle
   * @return Rectangle object that represents the overlap of the two rectangles
   * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if no intersection exists
   */
  public Rectangle intersect(Rectangle other) throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (!this.overlap(other)) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Rectangles do not overlap");
    }
    int xBottomLeft = this.x;
    int yBottomLeft = this.y;

    int xTopRight = this.x + this.width;
    int yTopRight = this.y + this.height;

    int xBottomLeftOther = other.x;
    int yBottomLeftOther = other.y;

    int xTopRightOther = other.x + other.width;
    int yTopRightOther = other.y + other.height;

    int xBottomLeftInter = Math.max(xBottomLeft, xBottomLeftOther);
    int yBottomLeftInter = Math.max(yBottomLeft, yBottomLeftOther);

    int xTopRightInter = Math.min(xTopRight, xTopRightOther);
    int yTopRightInter = Math.min(yTopRight, yTopRightOther);

    if (xBottomLeftInter > xTopRightInter || yBottomLeftInter > yTopRightInter) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Rectangles do not overlap");
    }

    Rectangle interRect = new Rectangle(xBottomLeftInter, yBottomLeftInter,
            xTopRightInter - xBottomLeftInter, yTopRightInter - yBottomLeftInter);
    return interRect;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a Rectangle object that represents the union of this rectangle and the other rectangle.
   *
   * @param other the other rectangle
   * @return Rectangle object that represents the overlap of the two rectangles
   */
  public Rectangle union(Rectangle other) {
    int xBottomLeft = Math.min(this.x, other.x);
    int yBottomLeft = Math.min(this.y, other.y);

    int xTopLeft = xBottomLeft;
    int yTopLeft = Math.max(this.y + this.height, other.y + other.height);

    int xTopRight = Math.max(this.x + this.width, other.x + other.width);
    int yTopRight = yTopLeft;

    int xBottomRight = xTopRight;
    int yBottomRight = yBottomLeft;

    Rectangle unionRect = new Rectangle(xBottomLeft, yBottomLeft, xBottomRight - xBottomLeft,
            yTopLeft - yBottomLeft);
    return unionRect;
  }

  /**
   * Get the toString method of this rectangle.
   *
   * @return the toString method of this rectangle
   */
  public String toString() {
    return ("x:" + x + ", y:" + y + ", w:" + width + ", h:" + height);
  }
}
```

RectangleTest.java:

```js
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * A JUnit test class for the Rectangle class.
 */
public class RectangleTest {
  private Rectangle rect4;
  private Rectangle rect5;
  private Rectangle rect6;
  private Rectangle rect7;
  private Rectangle rect8;
  private Rectangle rect9;
  private Rectangle grader1;
  private Rectangle grader2;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    rect4 = new Rectangle(1,1,4,7);
    rect5 = new Rectangle(2,4,5,6);
    rect6 = new Rectangle(3, 5, 6, 4);
    rect7 = new Rectangle(2, 3, 49,4);
    rect8 = new Rectangle(-87,-45, 2,3);
    rect9 = new Rectangle(-1,-1,20,15);
    grader1 = new Rectangle(0,0,20,10);
    grader2 = new Rectangle(-50, -50, 5,5);
  }

  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void testTransmissionBoxIllegalArgumentException() {
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(-1,-2,-3,-4);
    Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(2, 4, -3, -3);
  }

  @Test
  public void testOverlap() {
    assertEquals(true, rect4.overlap(rect5));
    assertEquals(true, rect4.overlap(rect7));
    assertFalse("false", rect8.overlap(rect4));
    assertEquals(true, rect7.overlap(rect6));
    assertEquals(true, rect5.overlap(rect6));
    assertFalse("false", rect8.overlap(rect5));
    assertEquals(true, rect6.overlap(rect4));
    assertEquals(true, rect9.overlap(rect4));
    assertEquals(true, grader1.overlap(grader2)); // this should be false!!!

  }

  @Test
  public void testIntersect() {
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(2,4,3,4).toString(), rect4.intersect(rect5).toString());
  }

  @Test
  public void testUnion() {
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(1,1,6,9).toString(), rect4.union(rect5).toString());
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(1,1,6,9).toString(), rect5.union(rect4).toString());
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(-87,-45,106,59).toString(), rect8.union(rect9).toString());
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(-87,-45,106,59).toString(), rect9.union(rect8).toString());
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(2,3,49, 6).toString(), rect6.union(rect7).toString());
    assertEquals(new Rectangle(2,3,49,6).toString(), rect7.union(rect6).toString());
  }

  @Test
  public void testToString() {
    assertEquals("x:1, y:1, w:4, h:7", rect4.toString());
  }
}
```

Scoring Details: Junit grader
Selected test results

[image]

Comment: `assertEquals(true, grader1.overlap(grader2)); // this should be false!!!`  so why do u assert true ?

Comment: 1. It would be easier for you to debug if you separated the 'if` statement with multiple conditions to shorter several if statements. 2.By overlap you mean non empty intersection ? . 3. if (width > 0) and if (height > 0) in the constructor always return true.

Comment: @c0der No particular reason, just so all my tests passed, but this particular assertion should not pass. Just to show that it is passing. By overlap, I mean exactly what the javadocs states: " Returns true if this rectangle overlaps with other rectangle, false otherwise.
   *
   * param other, the other rectangle
   * return true, if this rectangle overlaps with other, false otherwise."
Yes the constructor is correct, it should not initialize non-negative width and height.

Answer (score 0):

When checking for overlap this condition 
`this.y > other.y + other.height && other.x < this.x + this.width` 
 
checks if "other max y is lower than this min y" which means NO overlap, so it can not be true what the two rectangles overlap.

The following is a simple set of conditions that checks if a vertical edge and horizontal edge of one rectangle cross edges of the other rectangle:

```
   public boolean overlap(Rectangle other) {

          //for overlap both vertical and horizontal edges need to cross 
          return    
                //check if horizontal edge cross 
                other.width + other.x > x &&   //other max x is bigger than min x and
                other.x < width + x   &&       //other min x is smaller than max x 
                //check if vertical edge cross                         
                other.height+ other.y > y &&
                other.y <height + y ;
  }
```

Some side notes: 
1.Don't use exceptions to control the regular flow of the program. Exceptions are just that: use them to handle run-time exceptions. For example, insted of:

```
if (!this.overlap(other)) {
  throw new NoSuchElementException("Rectangles do not overlap");
}
```

Use

```
if (!this.overlap(other)) {
  return null;
}
```

2. See comments

```
    if (height <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Height can't be non-positive.");
    }
    if (width <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width can't be non-positive.");
    }
    if (width > 0) { //width is always > 0 here so `if` is not needed 
      this.width = width;
    }
    if (height > 0) { //height is always > 0 here so `if` is not needed 
      this.height = height;
    }
```

3. Consider importing and using [java.awt.Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html)